# FastAPI showing only one query result

Tags: python, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI. I have a JSON data set,

```
data = {
    1: {
    "sn":1,
    "name": "A",
    "number": "1",
    "language": "de" 
    },
    2: {
    "sn":2,
    "name": "B",
    "number": "2",
    "language": "en"
    },
    3: {
    "sn":3,
    "name": "AB",
    "number": "3",
    "language": "en"
    }
}
```

I am using the "get" method to query data by "language". But whenever I am using "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data_lan?language=en" I am just getting only one(first) output. How do I get all the matched results?

```
@app.get("/data_lan")
def data_lan(language: str):
    for d in data:
        if data[d]["language"] == language:
            return data[d]
    return {"data": "NULL !!!"}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you return the data in your first match:

```
if data[d]["language"] == language:
    return data[d] # the function return here on first match
```

To overcome it, you could create a data holder `dict` or `list` depend on your API

```
@app.get("/data_lan")
def data_lan(language: str):
    responseData = list()
    for d in data:
        if data[d]["language"] == language:
            responseData.append(data[d])
    if responseData: # check if responseData not empty then return it
        return {"data": responseData}
    else: # else return null
        return {"data": "NULL !!!"}
```